# Magento 2 create order pragmatically saves only 1 product not 2

Tags: magento, magento2

i am using magento 2.1.5 while i create order pragmatically than it create only 1 product i need to save both product in order.

i debug foreach loop of order items i am getting both products are load properly.

```
    $orderData =[
    'currency_id'  => 'USD',
    'email'        => 'test@example.com',
    'shipping_address' =>[
    'firstname'    => 'Fake', //address Details
    'lastname'     => 'Name',
    'street' => 'xxxxx',
    'city' => 'xxxxx',
    'country_id' => 'IN',
    'region' => 'xxx',
    'postcode' => '43244',
    'telephone' => '52332',
    'fax' => '32423',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
],
'items'=> [
    ['product_id'=>'1','qty'=>1],
    ['product_id'=>'2','qty'=>1]
]
];

<?php
namespace Icecube\Measurements\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
 /**
* @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
* @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
* @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
* @param Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey $formkey,
* @param Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
* @param Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
* @param Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
*/
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate  
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_productFactory = $product;
    $this->_formkey = $formkey;
    $this->quote = $quote;
    $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->orderService = $orderService;
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    $this->_transaction = $transaction;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
    $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
    $this->shippingRate = $shippingRate;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function loadProduct() {
    $collection = NULL;
    return $collection = $this->productFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();
}

/**
 * Create Order On Your Store
 * 
 * @param array $orderData
 * @return array
 * 
*/
public function createOrderNew($orderData) {
    //init the store id and website id @todo pass from array
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    //init the customer
    $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
    //check the customer
    if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
        //If not avilable then create this customer
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
            ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
            ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
        $customer->save();
    }
    //init the quote
    $cart_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
    $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart_id);
    $cart->setStore($store);
    // if you have already buyer id then you can load customer directly
    $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
    $cart->setCurrency();
    $cart->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
    //add items in quote
    foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item['product_id']);
        $cart->addProduct(
            $product,
            intval($item['qty'])
        );
    }
    //Set Address to quote @todo add section in order data for seperate billing and handle it
    $cart->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    $cart->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
    $this->shippingRate
        ->setCode('freeshipping_freeshipping')
        ->getPrice(1);
    $shippingAddress = $cart->getShippingAddress();
    //@todo set in order data
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //shipping method
    //$cart->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->rate);
    $cart->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
    //@todo insert a variable to affect the invetory
    $cart->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    // Set sales order payment
    $cart->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
    // Collect total and saeve
    $cart->collectTotals();
    // Submit the quote and create the order
    $cart->save();
    $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart->getId());
    $order_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId());
    return $order_id;
}
}

?>
```